# How multiple Tween can provide value for the same property？

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm doing a cool animation, I've divided the whole animation into many segments, and I've calculated the proportion of time each segment takes. I plan to generate a `Tween` object for each time period, and then generate successive property values. But now I find that I can only provide a `Tween` object for a property, and a `Tween` object can only set a time slice.

How to provide value for the same property with multiple `Tween`? Or is there a better way without `Tween`?

```dart
class TextAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Animation<double> yOffset = Tween<double>(
      begin: .0,
      end: 180.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: const Interval(
          0.0,
          0.5,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
        ),
      ),
    );

    // The previous Tween is not working and has been overwritten
    yOffset = Tween<double>(
      begin: .0,
      end: -100.0,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: const Interval(
          0.5,
          1.0,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
        ),
      ),
    );
    
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, yOffset.value),
          child: const Text("Hello"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your idea but maybe this is what you need for segments https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/TweenSequence-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer provided by @pskink, some details will be encountered in the process of use, and I will also summarize it.

1. weight less than 100

`yOffset` ends animation before 1.0.

```dart
final Animation<double> yOffset = TweenSequence<double>(
  <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 0,
        end: 360,
      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
      weight: 36,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 360,
        end: 540,
      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
      weight: 20,
    ),
  ],
).animate(animationController);
```

2. Start from non-0.0

`yOffset` does not start animation from 0.0 time point, then you need to use `ConstantTween<double>(0)`.

```dart
final Animation<double> yOffset = TweenSequence<double>(
  <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(0),
      weight: 16,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 0,
        end: 360,
      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
      weight: 84,
    ),
  ],
).animate(animationController);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one tween like this:

```
  Animation<double> yOffset = Tween<double>(
  begin: 0,
  end: 1,
)
```

and after that change your value like this:

```
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: animationController,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(0, yOffset.value * 180 ), or Offset(0, yOffset.value * 100 )
      child: const Text("Hello"),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Sorry, `or` is not what I want, I want to control time. `pskink` is the answer I want

Comment: No problem, That's cool, I am glad that your problem solved...I voted for pskink's answer